# Xamarin.Forms CSS selector for custom control

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I have a custom control (MyControl) in my Xamarin.Forms project.
I wonder if it is possible to style my control with CSS? Currently I do not know how to specify a selector for my custom control.

If I style the control in XAML, I need to import a namespace and use it:

```
xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:DemoApp.Controls"
...
<Style TargetType="ctrls:MyControl"...
```

CSS also supports namespaces:

```
@namespace ctlrs "clr-namespace:DemoApp.Controls";
```

However, if I try to write a CSS rule...

```
ctrls|MyControl {
    margin: 10;
}
```

...I get a System.NotSupportedException: 'AT-rules not supported'.

So I wonder if there is a solution for custom control to be styled with CSS.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Elements with a specific class attribute can be selected with the case sensitive .class selector:

For example , set the style of `Label`

#### style.css

```
.detailPageTitle {
    font-style: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}

.detailPageSubtitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label ... StyleClass="detailPageTitle" />
            <Label ... StyleClass="detailPageSubtitle"/>
            
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

In your case , you should make sure that your custom control has the property `Margin`.

For more details about using CSS in xamarin.forms you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/) .

### Update

You can set the style as following

```
^MyControl {
                background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Or you can directly set it in xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <StyleSheet>
            <![CDATA[
            ^MyControl {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            ]]>
    </StyleSheet>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

  <conv:MyControl Text="1111111"/>
  <conv:MyControl Text="1111111"/>
  <conv:MyControl Text="1111111"/>
  <conv:MyControl Text="1111111"/>
          
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question, because it requires modifying all the instances of Label. Same can be achieved with style defined in XAML.

Comment: You can use it in Custom Control . My code is just for test .

Comment: Use what in custom control? Styled Label? Of course I can, but the question is how can I apply style to a custom control, not to a contents of custom control. Let's say I have a page with a hundred instances of MyControl? How can I style them all in XFs CSS? It is absolutely possible with XAML Style, but how can it be achieved via CSS?

Comment: Hm... I will try setting it from code behind and see what I can achieve.

Comment: I don't think you can do it .We can only reference the style of CSS in xaml or code behind . Which likes in Html . If you want to reference the style onetime(avoid setting them 100 times in xaml) . You can set the style in code behind .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200245/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-dima).

Answer (score 0):

**Select element by base class**

CSS in file `/Styles/styles.css` in Xamarin.Forms project:

```
   ^MyClass {
       font-style: italic;
   }
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
             ...
  >
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
    <StyleSheet Source="/Styles/styles.css" />
    ...
  </ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
    <myNamespace:MyClass Text="Text" />
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

[Note:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/#selecting-elements-by-base-class)

> The ^base selector is specific to Xamarin.Forms, and isn't part of the CSS specification.

Comment: If I use a selector for a base class - it will affect all the custom controls (if base class is a ContentView). If I create my own base class, I end up with the same problem: how to use namespace in CSS in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: As long as the new base class is given a different name than an existing base class (e.g. the new base class is not named "ContentView"), the "select element by base class" option should work - without bringing the namespace into the css.